# Integration: $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

My teacher wrote this on the blackboard: $$\int_0^z \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx= \frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin(\sqrt{z})$$

But when I try to calculate the integral:

\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx&=\int \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}}dx\\
&=  \int \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2-k^2}}dk=2 \int \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-(2k)^2}}dk\\
&= \int \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-a^2}}da\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(a)\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin\left(2(x-\frac{1}{2})\right)
\end{align}

So

$$\int_0^z \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx= \frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(2z-1)-\frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(-1)= \frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(2z-1) - \frac{1}{2}$$

How I come to the solution of my teacher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you make the substitution $x=u^2$ the integral becomes:
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{z}} \frac2{\pi \sqrt{1-u^2}}du
$$

Comment: thanks!, but under the assumption that $z>0$.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer should be $$\frac {1}{\pi}\arcsin(2z-1)\color{red}{+}\frac 12$$

In fact both answers are equivalent. This is because if $$\phi=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(\sqrt{z}),$$ then$$\sin(\pi\phi)=2\sqrt{z}\cos(\arcsin(\sqrt{z}))=2\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-z}\Rightarrow\phi=\frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin(2\sqrt{z-z^2})$$

Meanwhile, if $$\theta=\frac {1}{\pi}\arcsin(2z-1)\color{red}{+}\frac 12,$$ then$$\sin(\pi\theta)=\sin(\arcsin(2z-1)+\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$=\cos(\arcsin(2z-1))=\sqrt{1-(2z-1)^2}=2\sqrt{z-z^2}$$

Hence $$\phi=\theta$$